# C# lambda function meaning and C++ translation

Tags: c#, c++, lambda

I'm trying to translate from C# to C++ a filtering function for an image that I found on Internet, so I can compile a DLL and use it in my project.
The original C# code is:

```
    Parallel.For(0, height, depthArrayRowIndex => {
        for (int depthArrayColumnIndex = 0; depthArrayColumnIndex < width; depthArrayColumnIndex++) {
            var depthIndex = depthArrayColumnIndex + (depthArrayRowIndex * width);
            .
            .
            .
            ... other stuff ...
    }
```

The first part of my question is: how

```
    depthArrayRowIndex => {
```

works?
What meaning has `depthArrayRowIndex` in:

```
    var depthIndex = depthArrayColumnIndex + (depthArrayRowIndex * width);
```

This is my C++ translation:

```
    concurrency::parallel_for(0, width, [&widthBound, &heightBound, &smoothDepthArray] () {
        for (int depthArrayColumnIndex = 0; depthArrayColumnIndex < width; depthArrayColumnIndex++) {
            int depthIndex = depthArrayColumnIndex + (depthArrayRowIndex * width);
            .
            .
            .
            ... other stuff ...
    }
```

but obviously here `depthArrayRowIndex` has no meaning.
How can I translate the C# code in a working one in C++?

Thank you very very much !!!   :-)

Comment: It's an argument to the lambda.

Comment: sorry... I'm very stupid !! can you please explain me better what an argument of a lambda function is for?

Comment: To pass something to the lambda, same as argument to function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case "depthArrayRowIndex" is the input parameter of the lambda function, so in your C++ version, you might want to change

```
[&widthBound, &heightBound, &smoothDepthArray] ()
```

for

```
[&widthBound, &heightBound, &smoothDepthArray] (int depthArrayRowIndex)
```

If you want to read further about C# lambda syntax, this link might be useful

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Foo => {
  // code
  return bar; // bar is of type Bar
}
```

is the same as

```
(Foo) => {
  // code
  return bar; // bar is of type Bar
}
```

to translate this to C++ do

```
[&](int Foo)->Bar {
  // code
  return bar; // bar is of type Bar
}
```

assming `Foo` is of type `int`.  In C++, single-line lambdas can have the `->Bar` portion skipped.  Lambdas that don't return anything can have `->void` skipped.

You can list the captured arguments (and if they are captured by value or reference) inside the `[]` of the C++ lambda, but C# lambdas do the equivalent of capturing everything used implicitly by smart reference.  If the lifetime of your lambda is limited to the scope that the C++ lambda is created in, `[&]` is equivalent.

If it could last longer, you need to deal with lifetime management of the data that the lambda captures, and you'll want to be far more careful and only capture by value (and possibly pack your data into `shared_ptr` before capturing the `shared_ptr`).

Comment: Yes. *by value* is very important!

Answer (score 0):

`depthArrayRowIndex` will be basically the index variable/value of your (parallel) outer for loop. It'll go from `0` inclusive to `height` exclusive:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783539.aspx

A little explanation (C#): the whole third argument of the parallel for is the lambda function, the action gets an Int32 parameter and it happens to be the loop index.

So I think your C++ translation should start as:
`concurrency::parallel_for(0, height, ...` instead of `width`.